# Why do I get "NaN" as Outprint`?

Tags: java, pi

I want to calculat Pi with Java. With  S. Ramanujan formel.

Heres my code:

```
public class PiV5 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
int a = 4;
double pi = 0;
int b = 3;
int fakult = 3;

int x = 3; 
long y = 1;
    for (int i =1; i <= 50; i++) {
        int n = i*4; 
        long fakultaet = 1;
        long fakultae2 = 1; 
        int bh = i;
        for (int g=1; g<=n; g++) {fakultaet = fakultaet * g;}
        for (int l=1; l<=bh; l++) {fakultae2 = fakultae2 * l;}

        pi = ((fakultaet * (1103 + (26390*i)))/Math.pow(fakultae2, 4) * Math.pow(396, 4*i));

    };
        System.out.println("Pi nach ein paar Rechnungen: " + (Math.sqrt(8)/9801)*pi);

    }
}
```

Thanks for ur help, if you could help me

Comment: Why are you calculating the value 50 times, but only printing the last result? What is the purpose of `a`, `b`, `fakult`, `x`, and `y`?

Comment: **Numeric overflow:** `50!` = 30414093201713378043612608166064768844377641568960512000000000000 which *greatly* exceeds the max value of a `long` (9223372036854775807). This doesn't even account for the even larger overflow of `200!`

Comment: *In case you didn't know:* To "calculate" pi in Java, use [`Math.PI`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#PI)

Comment: @Andreas Because he wants to implement [Ramanujan’s Formula for Pi](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/pi/ramanujan.html) in Java.

Comment: *Hint:* To perform that calculation, without causing numeric overflow, replace `double` and `long` with [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

Comment: @Andreas Yeah I know but I have no life, lol. I will try it with BigDecimal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Andreas mentioned in the comments this calculation results in a numeric overflow, because the values getting to large even for long data types.

The maximum steps you can do with your algorithm right now is `5`, because `20! = 2432902008176640000`, `21! = -4249290049419214848` which is caused by the numeric overflow.

But even then you have a little error in your code, because you forgot to sum up the values in the loop:

```
pi += ((fakultaet * (1103 + (26390 * i))) / Math.pow(fakultae2, 4) * Math.pow(396, 4 * i));
```

To get a better accuracy also use double values for the constant values:

```
pi += ((fakultaet * (1103d + (26390d * i))) / Math.pow(fakultae2, 4) * Math.pow(396, 4 * i));
```

Using that with 5 iterations will result in the following:

```
Pi nach ein paar Rechnungen: 4.0513767058512194E63
```

This is not quite a good result for PI.

To improve it and get better accuracy you could use [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class.